# In PHP, using file_get_contents && file_get_contents returns different values?

Tags: php, string, if-statement, boolean, file-get-contents

I was doing a mild test with the `file_get_contents`.  The aim is to test if `2 urls` do exist then see if they both have a certain `string` in them.

**Something like:**

```
$check_url1 = "www.example_1.com";
$check_url2 = "www.example_2.com";


if( 
$view_loaded_url1= @file_get_contents($check_url1)&&
$view_loaded_url2= @file_get_contents($check_url2)  )                                                            
{

    var_dump($view_loaded_url1); //RETURNS boolean true 

    var_dump($view_loaded_url2); //Returns the Contents of the page i.e: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Str.....etc
```

How do you make both return the `contents` of the page and not the `boolean`?

Because there is a second `if` to check if they both contain a certain `string`.

**Something like:**

```
if(stristr($view_loaded_url1, 'I am the String') && stristr($view_loaded_url2, 'I am the String') {

//....This part cannot go through because $view_loaded_url1 and $view_loaded_url2 are returning different datatype

}
```

Is this a normal behavior?.... has anyone else encountered this?

**SCREENSHOT:**
[image]

Comment: Have you tried using brackets?

Comment: @Phil_1984_  Nop.... how to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`file_get_contents` never returns `true`. 
It returns file (or URL) contents or `false` if the contents retrieval failed.

The reason that `$view_loaded_url1` gets the value `true` is that the expression is evaluated as follows (see parentheses):

```
if( 
  $view_loaded_url1 = (@file_get_contents($check_url1) && ($view_loaded_url2 = @file_get_contents($check_url2))
  )
```

The fix is to group the operators:

```
if( 
  ($view_loaded_url1 = @file_get_contents($check_url1)) &&
  ($view_loaded_url2 = @file_get_contents($check_url2))
  )                                                            
{
```

Comment: In nerd words, logical and (`&&`) has [higher precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) than assignment (`=`).

Comment: @ErickBest, ... if at least one of the URLs can be fetched and the fetched contents is [not empty and not the string `"0"`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php)

Comment: sure, true... but i went with the grouping... funny enough, i never tried before to _test-load_ two documents at ago... this was the first time and it worked perfectly after grouping... ty!

Answer (score 0):

`file_get_contents` is not reliable way of checking if the url exists or not. This function returns `false` boolean value for every non 2XX http response.

You better write your own function which would connect to the given url on port 80 via a socket and analyze the output or respond to the connection timeout. You can use the cURL as well.

Comment: This is true, and I agree with you, but this answer feels more like a comment without an example of a function that implements the suggestion.

Comment: @mike Am Interested!.... Could you recommend a better than `file_get_contents` solution?..(promise to UpVote)

Comment: Could you clarify what do you mean by "the url exists"? For instance the url can be 100% valid while the server-side software might indicate that  the requested resource is unavailable and respond with 404 in return

Comment: uhh?.... why would the `server-side software` give a 404?... Could you give a _test-case_ scenario? and the alternative to `file_get_contents`  ?

Comment: This could be a REST service or like I said the software might indicate the requested resource does not exist vide invalid ID passed in the URL. Still I cant provide any example until you clarify what do you mean by "existing url".

Comment: Existing url... a url that loads well in the web-browser with no problem